# Android - Save image from URL onto SD card

Tags: java, android, maps, emulation

I want to save an image from a URL to the SD card (for future use) and then load that image from the SD card to use it as a drawable overlay for Google maps.

Here is the save section of the function:

```
//SAVE TO FILE

String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
String extraPath = "/Map-"+RowNumber+"-"+ColNumber+".png";
filepath += extraPath;

FileOutputStream fos = null;
fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath); 

bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 75, fos);

//LOAD IMAGE FROM FILE
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filepath);
return d;
```

The image is saved to the sd card succuessfully but fails when getting to the `createFromPath()` line. I don't understand why it would save ok to that destination but not load from it....

Comment: Did you try loading an existing image using createFromPath?

Comment: It's in a try-catch statement, setting it to null if it fails. I have not tested another image. I am using the Emulator

Comment: How to save an image from firebase storage to SD card. I'm not able to figure out. can you please help me out with this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43765215/7004388)

Answer (score 28):

***Try this code.It works...***

```
try
{   
  URL url = new URL("Enter the URL to be downloaded");
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
  urlConnection.connect();                  
  File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
  String filename="downloadedFile.png";   
  Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
  if(file.createNewFile())
  {
    file.createNewFile();
  }                 
  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
  int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  int downloadedSize = 0;   
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bufferLength = 0;
  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
  {                 
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
  }             
  fileOutput.close();
  if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();    
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
  filepath=null;
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ;
return filepath;
```

Comment: Dude! this code really does work!Thanks a lot for this snippet

Comment: I don't get why you do this:

if(file.createNewFile())
  {
    file.createNewFile();
  }

Comment: dude, i was looking for code from 2 hour and finally this works :)  thanks a lot upvoted :)

Comment: I get filepath null every time. Can anybody tell how set filepath?

Comment: This code will be more better if placed inside async task

Comment: @Giridharan Hey I am getting error message "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:" by using this URL "www.androhub.com/demo/demo.pdf" Any ideas why is it so?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code to save the Image from the URL to SDCard.

```
URL url = new URL ("file://some/path/anImage.png"); 
InputStream input = url.openStream(); 
try {     
    File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath, "myImage.png");     
    try {         
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];         
        int bytesRead = 0;         
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);         
        }     
    }   
    finally {         
        output.close();     
    } 
} 

finally {     
    input.close(); 
}
```

If you want to create a sub directory on the SD card use:

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Wallpaper");
storagePath.mkdirs();
```

To create a the sub directory "/sdcard/Wallpaper/".

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue and resolved mine with this. Try this

```
private class ImageDownloadAndSave extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
        {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) 
            {           
                downloadImagesToSdCard("","");
                return null;
            }

               private void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl,String imageName)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        URL url = new URL(img_URL); 
                        /* making a directory in sdcard */
                        String sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();     
                        File myDir = new File(sdCard,"test.jpg");

                        /*  if specified not exist create new */
                        if(!myDir.exists())
                        {
                            myDir.mkdir();
                            Log.v("", "inside mkdir");
                        }

                        /* checks the file and if it already exist delete */
                        String fname = imageName;
                        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                        if (file.exists ()) 
                            file.delete (); 

                             /* Open a connection */
                        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                        InputStream inputStream = null;
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)ucon;
                        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();

                          if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                          {
                           inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                          }

                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  
                int totalSize = httpConn.getContentLength();
                        int downloadedSize = 0;   
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bufferLength = 0;
                        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) >0 ) 
                        {                 
                          fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
                          downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
                          Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
                        }   

                            fos.close();
                            Log.d("test", "Image Saved in sdcard..");                      
                    }
                    catch(IOException io)
                    {                  
                         io.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {                     
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }           
        }
```

Declare your network operations in AsyncTask as it will load it as a background task. Don't load network operation on main thread.
After this either in button click or in content view call this class like

```
 new ImageDownloadAndSave().execute("");
```

And don't forget to add the nework permission as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope this may help someone :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's failing because you're writing a compressed version of the bitmap to the output stream, which should be loaded with `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Have a [quick look](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) at the documentation on this.

If you need a `Drawable` (`decodeStream()` returns a `Bitmap`), simply call `Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)`.

Comment: I've decoded using the 'decodeStream' - how do I now turn that to a Drawable ?

Comment: Simply call `Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)`, where `bitmap` is the result of calling `decodeStream()`. I've updated my answer above with this information.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code..It works fine**

```
public static Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
            URL m;
            InputStream i = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out =null;
            try {
                m = new URL(url);
                i = (InputStream) m.getContent();
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(i,1024 * 8);
                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int len=0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                out.close();
                bis.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            //Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(i, "src");
            return bitmap;
        }
```

and save the bitmap into directory

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "test.jpg")
f.createNewFile();
//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

// remember close de FileOutput
fo.close();
```

and do not forget to add permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... An easy way to the task done.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(url)
                .into(new Target() {
                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                              try {
                                  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                  File myDir = new File(root + "/yourDirectory");

                                  if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                      myDir.mkdirs();
                                  }

                                  String name = new Date().toString() + ".jpg";
                                  myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                  out.flush();
                                  out.close();
                              } catch(Exception e){
                                  // some action
                              }
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                          }
                      }
                );
```