# How to Store Image in SDCard using Service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am getting the Image URL and set that URL in GridView.it shows me Successfully in Gridview.But I also want to Store That Images in SDCard Using Service.How to do That.Please Someone Help me for my this Issue.Thank You.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
GridView gv;
String TAG = "GRIDVIEW";
LazyAdapter adapter;
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    new loading().execute();
    // gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    // startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
    // gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    // gv.setAdapter(new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, mStrings));
    // gv.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
    // gv.setVerticalSpacing(40);

    // gv.setGravity(200);

}

ProgressDialog mprogress;

private class loading extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mprogress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mprogress.setMessage("Loading...");
        mprogress.show();

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        getGirdview();
        mprogress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    private void getGirdview() {
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gv.setAdapter(new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, mStrings));
        gv.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
        gv.setVerticalSpacing(40);
    }

}

public String[] mStrings = {

        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG.png",
        };
    }

public class MyService extends Service {

String TAG = "GRIDVIEW";
Bitmap bitmap;
MainActivity mclass = new MainActivity();

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mclass.mStrings.length; i++) {

        String str = mclass.mStrings[i];
        bitmap = DownloadImage(str);
        // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        // R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File storagePath = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Wallpaper");
        storagePath.mkdirs();

        String fileName = "test" + i + ".png";
        File dest = new File(storagePath, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onStart(intent, startId);

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // for (int i = 0; i < mStrings.length; i++) {
    //
    // String str = mStrings[i];
    // bitmap = DownloadImage(str);
    // // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    // // R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    // // File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // File storagePath = new File(
    // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Wallpaper");
    // storagePath.mkdirs();
    //
    // String fileName = "test" + i + ".png";
    // File dest = new File(storagePath, fileName);
    // try {
    // FileOutputStream out;
    // out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    // out.flush();
    // out.close();
    // } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // } catch (IOException e) {
    // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }
    // }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

// public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
//
// for (int i = 0; i < mStrings.length; i++) {
//
// String str = mStrings[i];
// bitmap = DownloadImage(str);
// // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
// // R.drawable.ic_launcher);
// // File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// File storagePath = new File(
// Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Wallpaper");
// storagePath.mkdirs();
//
// String fileName = "test" + i + ".png";
// File dest = new File(storagePath, fileName);
// try {
// FileOutputStream out;
// out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
// bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
// out.flush();
// out.close();
// } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// // TODO Auto-generated catch block
// e.printStackTrace();
// } catch (IOException e) {
// // TODO Auto-generated catch block
// e.printStackTrace();
// }
// }
// super.onStart(intent, startId);
// }

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
}

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Image is Downloaded",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return bitmap;
}

public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}



private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
String TAG = "GridView";
private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
Bitmap bitmap;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    }

    // TextView txt_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // txt_name.setText("item" + position);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    // image.setTag(data[position]);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875114/android-save-image-from-url-onto-sd-card

Comment: yes I am getting it.But I want to do it by Using Service.How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Environment.getExternalStorage() will return the sd card location. Once you get the location, you can create directories as needed. Looks like you are doing it....so what is the issue that you are running into?

Also, use IntentService rather than a service......it takes care of most of the plumbing work for you.

Comment: i want to store that images in SDcard using Service.I tried a lot.But Still not getting it.Please Help me for this.