# How to correctly form URL to display Bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I try to download image by URL but keep getting

`D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null`

in logs. I assume this is because my URL is malformed. How do I download it correctly? This is how I'm downloading the image right now:

```
URL imageUrl = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/YellowbilledLoon23.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Edit: As CommonsWare suggested in the comments, the solution for me was changing URL from `http` to `https`.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into a library like Picasso for image loading, not that it answers your question.

Comment: The URL opens in a web browser. It does not appear to be malformed.

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648729/3678308??

Comment: That URL issues an HTTP 301 redirect to the `https` edition of the URL. Try using the `https` edition directly. Then, switch to an image-loading library, as zgc7009 suggests.

Comment: @Javacoder  I get the same message.

Comment: @CommonsWare changing `http` to `https` worked! Thanks!

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
URL imageUrl = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/YellowbilledLoon23.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```