# Downloading an Image from firebase storage fails: android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Downloading the image and storing it on SD card doesn't work. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

This code is for uploading an Image to Firebase Storage.

```
// Get a reference to store file at photos/<FILENAME>
StorageReference photoRef = mPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

//Upload file to Firebase Storage
photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    Log.d("TAG", "in Success method of Uploading file");
    // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
    Message message = new Message(null, userName, downloadUrl.toString());
    messagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Note that, I used the following for creating the local image file:

```
File localFile = null;
    try {
      localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg", getExternalFilesDir(null));
      Log.d("TAG", "local file: " + localFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I'm taking the same `photoRef` to download that particular image the user uploads. Is this a right way of doing?

```
photoRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
        Log.d("TAG", "Entered onSuccess in Download File*");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
        Log.d("TAG", "Entered onFailure in Download File*");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

I logged the value of `photoRef` and `local file`. This showed on my **LogCat**.

```
Photoref: gs://wecare-8a15d.appspot.com/photos/image:27410
local file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pc.wecare/files/images2116155570jpg
```

This is the exception that I got when i used exception.getMessage();

```
Excecption message: Object does not exist at location.
```

This are the details from **LogCat**. It shows from picking up a photo from gallery and uploading it to Firebase Storage:

```
05-03 11:25:11.600 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: In Main Activity Pause Method
05-03 11:25:20.277 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: Entered OnActivity photo picker method
05-03 11:25:20.277 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: onActivityResult, requestCode: 2, resultCode: -1
05-03 11:25:20.278 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: onActivityResult, RC_PHOTO_PICKER: 2, RESULT_OK: -1
05-03 11:25:20.310 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: local file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pc.wecare/files/images306346474jpg
05-03 11:25:20.310 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: Photoref: gs://wecare-8a15d.appspot.com/photos/image:27301
05-03 11:25:20.313 8577-8577/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: In Main Activity Resume Method
05-03 12:58:14.730 31570-31570/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: Entered onFailure in Download File*
05-03 12:58:17.234 31570-31570/com.pc.wecare D/TAG: in Success method of Uploading file
```

Comment: The log output shows _Entered onSuccess in Download File_.  What's the failure?

Comment: That's it. This is what it was shown on my Logcat. I suppose It didn't enter `onFailure` @BobSnyder

Comment: The log output indicates the download was successful.  Are you not finding the file where you expect it to be?

Comment: yes exactly! It shows that the download was successful but I'm not able to see that file on my Mobile Gallery or the SD Card Directory. @BobSnyder

Comment: I see you have updated the posted log output and now it is showing download failure.  Change your log statement to output the reason for the failure: `exception.getMessage()` and post the output.

Comment: Just edited my question. so this is what I got - `Excecption message: Object does not exist at location.`

Comment: Are you trying to download the file you just uploaded?  If so, the order of the log output suggests you are not waiting for the upload to complete before downloading. _in Success method of Uploading file_ is the last line output, **after** the download failure message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143321/discussion-between-pc-and-bob-snyder).

Answer (score 0):

1. please check your permission in manifest
2. File.createTempFile( fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());

This is not file extension

please check your file path

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pc.wecare/files/**images2116155570jpg**
images211615557**0.jpg**

Comment: May i know what happens when I add the 2nd point you mentioned? So you want me to edit `File.createTempFile("images", "jpg", getExternalFilesDir(null));` to `File.createTempFile( fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());` ?

Comment: right!  
or
File  file = new File(this.getCacheDir(), filename);
file.createNewFile();

Comment: please add .(dot) 
 localFile = File.createTempFile("images", ".jpg", getExternalFilesDir(null));